# Radiogroup to select default from iterated rows of formArray in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, forms, reactive, formarray

I have a problem that feels like it should have a simple solution, but it's evading me. Hoping someone can help out.

I have a reactive form set up with some defaults:

```
  IMSIForm = this.fb.group({
    imsi: '',
    uplink: 1000,
    uplinkUnit: 'Mbps',
    downlink: 1000,
    downlinkUnit: 'Mbps',
    deviceType: 'Phone',
    defaultAPN: '',
    APNList: this.fb.array([]),
  });
```

On a particular user interaction, the APNList array is populated with a variable-length list of objects via a function:

```
  addAPNRow(apn: string, isSelected: Boolean, isDefault: boolean, ip: string) {
    const apnGroup: FormGroup = this.fb.group({
      apn: [apn, Validators.required],
      isSelected: [isSelected, Validators.required],
      isDefault: [isDefault, Validators.required],
      ipAddress: [ip],
    });

    this.APNList.push(apnGroup);
  }
```

After that happens, the form data looks like this:

```
APNList: Array(6)
0: {apn: 'maca', isSelected: false, isDefault: false, ipAddress: '1.1.1.1'}
1: {apn: 'gs.net', isSelected: false, isDefault: false, ipAddress: '1.1.1.1'}
2: {apn: 'test', isSelected: false, isDefault: false, ipAddress: '1.1.1.1'}
3: {apn: 'mmg', isSelected: false, isDefault: false, ipAddress: '1.1.1.1'}
4: {apn: 'test22', isSelected: false, isDefault: false, ipAddress: '1.1.1.1'}
5: {apn: '6300-test', isSelected: false, isDefault: false, ipAddress: '1.1.1.1'}
deviceType: "Phone"
downlink: 1
downlinkUnit: "Mbps"
imsi: 505230001000006
uplink: 1
uplinkUnit: "Mbps"
```

All good so far.

The challenge I'm facing is to do with setting up a radiobutton for the user to select a default value from the list that's inserted into the array above.

The form will look essentially like this:

[image]

So the user can tick those entries that they wish to associate with the instance of the form then from the selected checks, use the radio button to set the default

```
<ng-container formArrayName="APNList">
  <ng-container *ngFor="  let APNRow of APNList.controls;  let i = index">
    <div fxFlexfxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start start"  fxLayoutGap="4px grid">
      <ng-container [formGroupName]="i">
        <div fxFlex="110px">
          <mat-checkbox formControlName="isSelected">{{ APNRow.value.apn }}</mat-checkbox>
        </div>

        <div fxFlex="80px">
          <mat-radio-button></mat-radio-button>
        </div>
      </ng-container>
    </div>
  </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

The radiobutton in there is not how it should be set up, I know, it's just a placeholder in the code to show where I need it.

The output that I need is to have a single radiogroup that spans the verical iterations of the formarray, with the output of the form to look like:

[image]

Hoping someone can help me with the correct way to set up the radiogroup and/or any corrections to the whole approach. Maybe I'm doing this whole thing wrong...?

Comment: @GRD, yes sure. The radiogroup needs to be shown to the user as a vertical list of radio buttons per the image below the comment. From their perspective, they need to select with the checkboxes one or many of the options, but only one of the selected options may be flagged as a the default - hence the radiogroup. All of the objects in the formArray have a property called 'isDefault' and this radiogroup will set just one of them to 'true' based on user selection.

Comment: unchecked checkboxes will disable the corresponding radio button - so if there's two checkboxes selected, then one of those will be able to be chosen as default with the radio

Comment: @GRD, thank you, yes, that will do exactly what I'm after.

Comment: @GRD shall do. Just one small detail that's not quite right in the solution, if you could check for me: the output of the form shows undefined for all values of the radiogroup, not a true for the selected one. Some small detail missing there, and I'm not sure what to do to fix.